# (JasperReports) Using JRBeanCollection as DataSource, and handle it in the jrxml

Tags: java, jasper-reports

So, I obtain a list of DAO from my database, and then I pass a JRBeanCollectionDataSource to the fill method. This works (makes an empty PDF).

```
public void reportTest() {
    AwardDAO awardDAO = new AwardDAOImpl();
    List<Award> awards = null;

    try{

        awards = awardDAO.getAllAwards();
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(awards);

        JasperReport jasperReport =
        JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/main/resources/hellojasper.jrxml");

        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        parameters.put("title", "Award Report");

        JasperPrint jasperPrint =
                JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, ds);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(
                jasperPrint, "Awards.pdf");

       }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**I don t know how to handle the info in the .jrxml file**. I have searched for a while but I only got more confused.
I want to display a simple table.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must declare fields in jrxml corresponding getters in Award and use this fields in textField expressions of report. That's all.
See example

[stackoverflow.com/questions/21432871/accessing-the-only-java-bean-passed-to-jasper-records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432871/accessing-the-only-java-bean-passed-to-jasper-records)

P.S. Are you sure that reportTest.**class** know about path "**src**/main/resources/hellojasper.jrxml" at your application?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Award class has getters and setters for each field you want to display in the PDF file.

For example if I want to display a Product class with the following fields:

```
<field name="productName" class="java.lang.String">
<field name="quantity" class="java.lang.String">
<field name="unitPrice" class="java.lang.String">
<field name="total" class="java.lang.String">
```

I can use a POJO to represent the Product class:

```
public class Product {
    private String productName;
    private String quantity;
    private String unitPrice;
    private String total;

    public void setProductName(String productName){
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductName(){return productName;}

    public void setQuantity(String quantity){
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getQuantity(){return quantity;}

    public void setUnitPrice(String unitPrice){
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public String getUnitPrice(){return unitPrice;}

    public void setTotal(String total){
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getTotal(){return total;}
}
```

And then I can create a JRBeanCollectionDataSource:

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
// Code to fill products
JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(products);
```